# Setting cache-control headers for nginx ingress controller on kubernetes GKE

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress-nginx controller handling traffic to my Kubernetes cluster hosted on GKE. I set it up using helm installation instructions from docs:

[Docs here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

For the most part everything is working, but if I try to set cache related parameters via a `server-snippet` annotation, all of the served content that should get the cache-control headers comes back as a `404`.

Here's my `ingress-service.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "4000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "4000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* \.(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 1M;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-com
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
       paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
            servicePort: 5000
        - path: /api/
          backend:
            serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
            servicePort: 4000
```

Again, it's only the resources that are matched by the regex that come back as `404` (all `.js` files, `.css` files, etc.).

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Those `location` blocks are [last and/or longest match wins](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), and since the ingress **itself** is not serving any such content, the nginx relies on a [`proxy_pass` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) pointing at the upstream server. Thus, if you are getting 404s, it's very likely because *your* `location` is matching, thus interfering with the `proxy_pass` one. There's a pretty good chance you'd actually want [`configuration-snippet:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) instead, likely in combination with [`if ($request_uri ~* ...) {`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) to add the header.

One can try this locally with a trivial nginx.conf pointing at `python3 -m http.server 9090` or whatever fake upstream target.

Separately, for debugging nginx ingress problems, it is often invaluable to consult its actual `nginx.conf`, which one can grab from any one of the ingress Pods, and/or consulting the logs of the ingress Pods where nginx will emit helpful debugging text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The `configuration-snippet` approach worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, I did peak at `nginx.conf` file on the relevant pod, but it was >1300 lines and I'm an nginx noob :)  Your insight has made me a little smarter.

Comment: for me itrs not working with  configuration-snippet . am adding like this

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($uri ~ '/app/.*') {
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=60"; `

but  it results
`cache-control: public, max-age=0`

Comment: (a) please don't use the comments section to ask a questions, post your own; (b) when you do ask your own question in the future, you'll want to be sure to pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section demonstrating that you added this to one Ingress, in isolation, and it didn't do what you said, versus all the other contributing factors in your setup that could interfere with your presumption. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Configuration-snippet will work with nginx ingress

you can use something like

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet : |
      if ($request_uri ~* \.(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)) {
        expires 1M;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
```

Comment: for me itrs not working with  configuration-snippet . am adding like this

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($uri ~ '/app/.*') {
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=60"; `

but  it results
`cache-control: public, max-age=0`

Comment: @BibekMantree I am facing the same issue. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to this. You can actually do the ingress way to handle this static content request(dynamically), without editing nginx.conf .
Moreover nginx.conf is dynamically created/edited by the ingress-nginx controller every time you make changes in the ingress object. Making changes or mounting the nginx.conf file can create issues.

For the Static files, use the below snippet to redirect your request to the correct service.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      expires 1M;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xx.xx.com
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /status/.*
          backend:
            service:
              name: one-service
              port:
                number: 80
  - host: xx.xx.com
     http:
       paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /.*(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)
          backend:
            service:
              name: static-app-service
              port:
                number: 80
  - host: xx.xx.com
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /
          backend:
            service:
              name: third-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

Use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` for redirecting your static traffic to the correct service.

The above snippet will provide you the results as below:

1. Any request on xx.xx.com/status/ will be routed to `one-service`.
   More Example : 
   xx.xx.com/status/zenduty -> `one-service` 
   xx.xx.com/status/zenduty/incident -> `one-service` 
   xx.xx.com/status/anything -> `one-service`
2. Any request on xx.xx.com containing .png, .js, .css, .jpg, .gif or .jpeg will be routed to `static-app-service` 
   Example : 
   xx.xx.com/custom.js -> `static-app-service` 
   xx.xx.com/status/custom.js -> `static-app-service` 
   xx.xx.com/custom.css -> `static-app-service` 
   xx.xx.com/abc/zen/duty/custom.css -> `static-app-service` 
   xx.xx.com/status/custom.gif -> `static-app-service`
3. Any other request on xx.xx.com which doesn't contain (.png, .js, .css, .jpg, .gif or .jpeg) and do not start with (xx.xx.com/static/), will be routed to `third-service` 
   Example: 
   xx.xx.com/login -> `third-service` 
   xx.xx.com/xyz -> `third-service`

If you want to add another header to the snippet you can add it. My suggestion will be to create a separate ingress object for static content.

Below is how you can separate the above snippet and add more headers on custom service levels.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      expires 1M;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xx.xx.com
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /.*(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)
          backend:
            service:
              name: static-app-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

The below snippet is for other services which do not have to serve the static content and have custom headers according to their requirements.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1";
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;includeSubdomains; preload";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: xx.xx.com
      http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /status/.*
          backend:
            service:
              name: one-service
              port:
                number: 80
  - host: xx.xx.com
     http:
       paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /
          backend:
            service:
              name: third-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

The ingress class name here is `ingressClassName: nginx`, please change accordingly.

This is the ingress way to route to the correct service.

If you want to pass client IP to your backend service , Check this for more details : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345240/updating-ingress-nginx-controller-configmap-to-pass-client-ip-to-backend-service/71407668#71407668](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233958/how-to-customize-error-pages-served-via-the-default-backend-of-an-nginx-ingress/71385359#71385359)

For Custom error page : [How to customize error pages served via the default backend of an nginx ingress controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233958/how-to-customize-error-pages-served-via-the-default-backend-of-an-nginx-ingress/71385359#71385359)