# Ingress ignores apache httpd caching

Tags: apache, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I run a apache-httpd based pod in our Rancher(Kubernetes). This httpd serves some static html+javascript+css files. Further I placed a `.htaccess` file in the `htdocs` folder. This file controls how caching should be done. My `index.html` file must not be cached at all. Browsers should load this file every time and should not cache it. But js files (that are referenced in the index.html file) must be cached. I can do this, because each file name of .js files contains a hash. If the content of the .js file is changed the file name changes through compiling it.

Content of the .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 weeks"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Now I have an Ingress that is placed before the Deployment (and the respective service):

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ui
  namespace: ui
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /ui(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 80
```

**Problem**. If I start my httpd-docker iamge on my laptop the caching works great. But if the pod is deployed in Kubernetes, it seams that cache configuration of my httpd is ignored. I supect that Ingress somehow breaks the caching.

**Question**: What needs to be done that my Ingress uses "the same" caching configuration as done in my httpd deployment?

Comment: Could you start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711061/setting-cache-control-headers-for-nginx-ingress-controller-on-kubernetes-gke) and let me know if it helped?

Comment: In addition please add : `allow-backend-server-header: "true"` to your nginx-ingress [nginx-ingress configMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#allow-backend-server-header) `Enables the return of the header Server from the backend` by default this parameter is disabled.

Comment: I can confirm that using nginx as backend with custom `Expires` settings for html and css (with nginx-ingress controller v0.34.1 and default configuration) preserve caching settings for html and css files. So please provide some reproducible example.